# Scollbar going behind footer in Firefox

Tags: css, html

This is the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sfctB/20/

```
html,body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

body
{
    padding: 60px 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header
{
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff; 
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
.body
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer
{
    height:60px;background:#000;position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;color:#fff;
    bottom:0
}
```

Basically I want the scrollbar only to appear in the content region and the header and footer should always appear at all time. The above link works in Chrome and IE but doesn't work in Firefox. The scrollbar goes behind the footer. Could anybody please explain me how do I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you might've to use one of those `webkit` etc. properties for FireFox.

Comment: Yes, Firefox still requires the `-moz` prefix for `box-sizing`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: hsan: That still doesn't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the -moz- and -webkit- and other necessary prefixes to the body.

```
body
{
padding: 60px 0px;
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;   // if supported?
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;  // if supported?
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfctB/53/

I would do away with the box-sizing if you think you can.

Answer (score 1):

I also came up with this if you want to get rid of box-sizing

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    padding: 60px 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
.body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    top:60px;
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}
.footer {
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
```

works on chrome and ff and ie

http://jsfiddle.net/sfctB/67/

don't know if that's valid though but I trust it more than anything that requires the prefix stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line of code in your body

```
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Your body will become somewhat like this

```
body
{
    padding: 60px 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Working fine in firefox ...
http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/5HRvq/

Answer (score -2):

The scrollbar goes behind the footer because your body class have height:100%;.so
see this link jsfiddle.net/sfctB/23/